# How to kill startup script?

Tags: boot, init.d

I just added a script to send me my ip-address of my pi via email as soon as it starts. Something went terrible wrong with it. On each boot I get a

`A start job is running for LSB: Raise network interfaces. (2min 58s/ no limit)`
Error on the console. I created a new file under `/etc/network/if-up.d/mailonconnect` and somehow this seems to destroy my pi.

Does anyone have an idea how to either cancel the wait for this startup job or how to access a terminal in that situation to remove and fix the startup script? For some reason CTRL + ALT + F1 for a tty doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just stick the card in another computer and remove the file?

Comment: For some reason I couldn't open the SD Card on my Mac (although I installed Fuse for OSX, see http://blog.gbaman.info/?p=328). But I just started from scratch again. Annoying, but it works. Thanks.

Comment: The script belongs into the directory `/etc/networrk/if-up.d`.

Comment: As u can see, the file has been in that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no solution, but i just reinstalled Rasbian.